# Excel - filter rows from multiple ranges

Tags: excel

I am trying to summarize rows from other tabs into a "main" tab. I would like to display the same structure of columns and the entire row.

The purpose is to go through the "sub-tabs" and "checkbox" next to a row to add it to the "main" tab. This needs to be done as you go along and mark a row.

The columns look something like this:

Checkbox | Value | Text | Value | Text

I'd like to filter with a rule which says that if(Checkbox<>"") then display the row. Is this possible to achieve without VBA?

Comment: How about selecting all your data and use Sort and Filter?

Comment: I need it to be automatic as you go along ticking boxes. Doing this process everytime they change the checkboxes is not suitable for the usage.

Comment: And why don't you want VBA to be involved?

Comment: Because where I work there are strict rules for macros etc. being used. They block the function.

Comment: @Dominique : Looks like no one knows how. I would be happy to know the VBA method of doing it. I can have a chat with IT about allowing it for the user of this sheet.